# Аннотация — к чему или на что?

Tags: трудности, недопустимая-метка

Как правильно говорить: аннотация к чему-то или аннотация на что-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русском языке слово "аннотация" может существовать аж в четырех падежах: в родительном (аннотация чего-то); в дательном (аннотация к чему-то); в винительном (аннотация на что-то); в предложном (аннотация о чем-то).
Все эти варианты будут верными.

Answer (score 0):

Аннотация на что? На фильм, на книгу — близко по значению к слову "рецензия". Но аннотация к чему? К написанному автором.